# Find patents by a specific patent attorney

Tags: espacenet

Many (pharmaceutical) companies have their own IP department employing many patent attorneys. On espacenet, which search field allows me to look for patents issued by a specific patent attorney at a specific pharmaceutical company? Usually, the PA is not the inventor, so I guess "inventor" is not where I should enter the PA.

Comment: I do not see a field for that in the Espacenet help section but WIPO'd PatentScope does have fields for this.

For queries related to LEGAL REPRESENTATIVES:
Fields     codes  examples
all data   RPA    RPA: (gearge, new port)
address    RAD    RAD: (colombettes)
country    RCN    RCN: KR
“Main Legal Rep” Name  RPF     RPF: (Jons)

Answer (score 2):

Espacenet doesnot provide search interface for legal representative filed applications. However PAID databases like Orbit, Thomson Reutors total patents etc provide such services.

Further if you wish you can search in WIPO search as they provide search for patent applications filed by legal representative.

[image]